# @OneToMany relationship in Spring REST controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Boot application working with Spring Data Rest. I have a domain entity `Post` which has a @OneToMany relationship to a domain entity `Comment`. For both entities I created a `Repository` interface.

So far, I have one controller called `PostController` which handles both entites. Via `http://localhost:8080/posts/1/` I get the post with Id 1. In addition, via `http://localhost:8080/posts/1/comments` I get all comments on the post with Id 1.

I wonder whether this is the right approach with a single controller for both entites or if I should write a single controller for each of the `Post` and `Comments` entities?

Comment: if you use spring data rest, this will be automatically created for you. Have you tried that?

Comment: Why are you using your own controllers with Spring Data Rest? You know that SDR creates "controllers" for you automatically right?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar project, my boss told me to use only a single `Repository` interface for both entities related like this. I will use only the `Post` entity-related `Repository`, not the `Comments` one, and then use the mapping to populate the `Comments` entity indirectly.

About the controller, I think it's okay, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using two repositories is the right approach since your database has the two entities stored in different tables. Perhaps some time in the future you'll need to search for comments and the second repository will help with this.

Regarding REST, your url looks good. So, if you don't need a new endpoint then a single controller sounds ok to me.

I would add a second controller if I had an endpoint that looked like this :

`http://localhost:8080/comments`